# Starting an Activity with Intent and SetClassName

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I am using the following code to move to another Activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
String test = "Navigate";  
intent.setClassName(this.context,test);  
intent.putExtra("params", params);  
((Activity) context).startActivity(intent);
```

But I am unable to start the Navigate Activity. No exception is thrown.
For the same, the folowing code works fine:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.context,Navigate.class);  
intent.putExtra("params", params); 
((Activity) context).startActivity(intent);
```

Please tell me if any work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the full classname, including the package:

```
String test = "your.package.here.Navigate";
```

(And the Activity defined in the Manifest, but as you can start it with `Navigate.class` I assume you have already done this).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the more explicit constructor: [`Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29). From the docs:

> [...] This provides a convenient way to create an intent that is
>   intended to execute a hard-coded class name, rather than relying on
>   the system to find an appropriate class for you [...]

This constructor internally calls the `setComponent()`-method, which is also called by your used `setClassName()`-method. But using the constructor spares you code-lines and makes the code more readable:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Navigate.class);
intent.putExtra("params", params);
this.startActivity(i);
```

Note that using `this` only works this way, when in an `Activity`, because the activity-class extends the `Context`-class.

Another advantage over hard-coding the package and class-names as a String is, that when you move a class to another package (or rename a package), you'll get compile-time errors, not runtime-errors.

Also, for this to work, you'll need to register the Activity in the Android Manifest.