# Way to find if an Activity Exists in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to test if the Activity by name "test" exists or not in the appliaction. May be using Manifest file before calling startActivity or in its catch block for the following:

[Starting an Activity with Intent and SetClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120655/starting-an-activity-with-intent-and-setclassname)

So say:

```
if(test.exists){  
    Activity is registered and start it    
}  
else{  
    create Activity and add it in manifset programmatically, as this would be a dynamic Activity    
}
```

Comment: if you share the need for it may be we can tell a work around.. Because you are trying to find if Activity exist in your own code which you can see... is there a specific need for it..?

Comment: yes.. i am developing a hybrid app, whic would laod a webview in one activity and on click of a button(say, callnative), it will call a Native Activity(say, test). This Activity name "test" will be coming in a JSON object and before starting that activity, I want t test if that exists

Comment: You will only be getting Activity name or you will get the package name too..?

Comment: i guess there is nothing you can do about it in manifest but create a template Activity that will be filled by your JSon

Comment: there might be "N" no. of Acitivities.!

Comment: then have a look at fragments.

Answer (score 0):

We cant add activities in manifeast file programmatically even if you get it from JSON response.

And if you are launching the native Activity we usually dont add them at all to manifeast file but for certain things we need to add permission to use them in our app.

Answer (score 0):

use forName instead..

something like this..

```
   try {
        Class<?> act = Class.forName("TestActivity");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//      do what you wish if not exist
    }
```

Comment: you have posted your answer and i think thats give the solution in this you can check and he can do something else what ever he else wants

Answer (score 0):

Manifest and so do other xmls present in apk cannot be modified.So yoou may have to re-use your components and you you can use fragments for that(if i understand your requirements correctly). or simply reuse a activity,

Checking the presence of Activity can be done easily .