# getting force close when i pass intent botween two activities using setcomponentname cunstructor

Tags: android, android-intent

Actually i am trying to implement `you tube API` in my android application .so here i am trying to start a activity that's extends a class which defined in same package from my `Main Activity` using intent but i am getting force to closed....
am giving my code bellow.....i hope anyone can help me and reply me immediately......thank you in advance

my main activity is :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void click(View v)
{



    Intent in=new Intent();
    in.setComponent(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), youtubevideos.class));

    startActivity(in);

}
```

you tube activity is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void click(View v)
{



    Intent in=new Intent();
    in.setComponent(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), youtubevideos.class));

    startActivity(in);

}
```

`

Comment: Have you looked at the log? I'd expect that to show an exception.

Comment: > hi refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120655/starting-an-activity-with-intent-and-setclassname

Comment: > Hi this link will help you[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120655/starting-an-activity-with-intent-and-setclassname

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  Intent in=new Intent(this, youtubevideos.class);
  startActivity(in);
```